# I have a problem connect to cloud sql from cloud run using prisma

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I am using Nestjs for the backend with Prisma.

Cloud SQL Postgres

I have a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    wget \
  ;
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
RUN chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy


COPY . .

ENV DATABASE_URL="postgresql://USER:PASSWORDH@localhost/postgres?host=/cloudsql/CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432"

ENV ENVIRONMENT="prod"
ENV DB_USER="DATABASE"
ENV DB_PASS="PASSWORD"
ENV DB_NAME="postgres"
ENV CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME="CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME"


RUN npx prisma generate
RUN npx prisma migrate deploy
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["sh", "-c", "./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=$CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 & npm run start:prod"]
```

I have searched the internet for a solution but found none!

the error

```
Step #0 - "Build": Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432`:`5432`
Step #0 - "Build": 
Step #0 - "Build": Please make sure your database server is running at `/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432`:`5432`.
Step #0 - "Build": The command '/bin/sh -c npx prisma migrate deploy' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

any help?

I have spent a lot of time trying to solve this error!

UPDATE!
I created a simple project with the same settings (and the same Dockerfile) and deployed it to cloud run. In this project, I didn't use Prisma and was able to connect to Cloud SQL. I think Prisma has some issues and I do see an issue open in their Github repo.

more about the issue https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1508

I am considering now switching to TypeORM.

So the conclusion is there is some problems with Prisma that it can't connect to Cloud SQL. There may be a solution out there but I am done and will use TypeORm. I am already using Nestjs and they have good support for Typeform

Comment: Show how you are building the container and deploying to Cloud Run.

Comment: I am using Github and giving google cloud access to trigger an action whenever I push to the master branch

Comment: OK and that action does something. Show exactly what the action does.

Comment: It just builds an image and containerizes it using the Dockerfile. 
it goes through all the steps until it reached ``` npx prisma migrate deploy``` this step requires connecting to the database. 
and after that it logs that it can't react the database

Comment: tep #0 - "Build": Step 35/39 : RUN npx prisma migrate deploy
Step #0 - "Build": Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Step #0 - "Build": Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "localhost:5432"
Step #0 - "Build": Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `/cloudsql/<CONNECTION_NAME>/.s.PGSQL.5432`:`5432`
Step #0 - "Build": Please make sure your database server is running at `/cloudsql/<CONNECTION_NAME>/.s.PGSQL.5432`:`5432`.
Step #0 - "Build": The command '/bin/sh -c npx prisma migrate deploy' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #0

Comment: Please edit your question and include details. I cannot read anything in the comments. Also not when deploying a Cloud Run application, you must specify the database. Review the command line options. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--set-cloudsql-instances

Comment: Hi John, I created a simple project with the same settings and deployed it to cloud run. In this project, I didn't use Prisma and was able to connect to Cloud SQL. 

I think Prisma have some issues and I do see an issue open in their Github repo

Comment: Thanks, John for your comments. You can check  more details about the issue here https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1508 
I have updated the question as well

Comment: @MohamedGad did you try without using the `.s.PGSQL.5432` part?  I was running into this same issue and that solved it for me.  This is in reference to the error log: `/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432`:`5432`.

Your env should look like this: `ENV DATABASE_URL="postgresql://USER:PASSWORDH@localhost/postgres?host=/cloudsql/CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME`.  You also should use Secrets Manager and not put secrets in your Docker container.  That's all in plain text and anybody with the image could steal your creds.